# Obtener recuento de listeners totales tipo $on('') activos en una aplicacion angularJs 1.xx

Tags: angularjs, depuración, rendimiento, out-of-memory-error

La idea es que estoy tratando de depurar en una Web angularJs 1.xx una gran cantidad de fugas de memoria (leak memory) y consumo de recursos que hacen que al tiempo de usarla la Web funcione mal o el navegador la detenga.

La web se basa en el ui-router para el ruteo. Dicen por ahí que podría crear fugas de memoria. Pero yo creo que es algo más.

He usado todas las herramientas del inpector del chrome y he comprobado que efectivamente el recolector de basura de javascript pierde referencias de muchos elementos del DOM , listeners y javascript.

Vi que esta web hace mucho usa desde los controladores de $emit('nombreEvento'), $broadcast('nombreEvento') , $whatch('elemento') y de los listeners tipo $on('nombreEvento'). Y los hace tanto dentro del $scope del controlador de la vista como del $rootScope, que creo más preocupante.

¿Existe alguna forma desde la consola en tiempo de depuración o libreria javascript que ayude entregar el recuento de listener y saber si se destruyen o no tal como debe según se navega por la web?

Ya uso un script que puesto en la consola me da el numero de watchers activos pero no se como contar el numero de listeners o escuchadores de eventos que va creando.

No me valen herramientas como BATARANG de angularJs porque esta web usa RequireJS que al modularizarla parece que BATARANG no funciona bien.

Me hallo un poco perdido y desesperado ya que necesito alguna herramienta para espiar que cada código que yo inserte para destruir eventos que no se necesiten realmente los elimina y arregla algo.

¿Alguien se ha visto alguna vez en esta situación?. 
Alguna idea por mínima que sea puede ayudarme. Es un tema, el del control del rendimiento y depuración de recursos que merece la pena considerar en angularJs pero que hasta ahora no me he visto en esta urgencia por mi trabajo.

Espero vuestra ayuda, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Buenas @Falinsito, comento para mantenerme al tanto por si puedo ayudar, como anécdota sufrir memory leaks con una app a causa de Jquery ya que la app estaba levantada durante días creando html y eliminándolo. A ver si entre unos cuantos podemos ayudar. Has podido identificar alguna parte de código angularJs que provoque siempre este comportamiento ? sería un buen punto de partida

Comment: Gracias, me has alegrado muchísimo con tu respuesta porque si que llevo ya mucho tiempo con este desarrollo tratando de arreglarlo en este sentido y es muy interesante cosas que ya he descubierto sobre angular. Voy a ir pasando algunas averiguaciones. Creo que es un tema muy muy importante que no te encuentras con el hasta que realmente pones en producción desarrollos de angular que te obligan a tenerlo en cuenta. Como dices, creo que merece un grupo de discusión muy muy exaustivo pero practico porque no abunda bien sobre esto.